# How do I get orientation working for one specific fragment of my app?

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation, screen-orientation, android-orientation

Before marking this question as duplicate, I would like to specify that I have a strange requirement I am running through. My app is supported by both phones and tablets, BUT orientation is supported ONLY by tablets and not by phones. I have restricted it to work only for tablets. But now, i have a strange issue, where I need to enable orientation in just one fragment in the phone. In my case say xfragment within x module. How do I go about that without removing the restriction on phones for not supporting orientations. Is there any other way around it? 
Currently in my fragment utils I am doing this:

```
public static void setActivityOrientation(Activity activity){
        boolean tabletSize = MyUtils.isTablet(activity);
        if (tabletSize) {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
        } else {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
    }
```

and calling it oncreate at base activity:

```
FragmentUtils.setActivityOrientation(this);
```

How do I make it work only for that particular fragment? Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If xfragment occupies whole screen, you can use the  same code above in proper life cycle of xfragment as

```
   public class XFragment  extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(!MyUtils.isTablet(getActivity())){
            getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(!MyUtils.isTablet(getActivity())){
            getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }

    }
}
```

Case 2:

If XFragment is not in full screen and you have multiple fragment, Then only way is to call detach and attach XFragment manually.

Comment: hi sowmia, that solution works, but it makes my whole phone work on landscape, how do I make ONLY one fragment work in landscape and not the whole app

Comment: @JusticeBauer, I didn't get ur point. we are resetting the orientation to portrait when we leave the fragment(onPause), then it how whole app gets landscape mode. Or do you have multiple fragments in that screen ?